# Keyboard Expression Pedal Position

Tags: piano, keyboard, keyboard-pedals, organ

I have a keyboard setup using a keyboard, a sustain pedal and an expression pedal. An image of my keyboard stand is below for reference. I am having trouble finding a good position for the expression pedal, because my knee hits the stand when I put my foot on the expression pedal. I saw some images of organs with expression pedals, which seem to be a bit higher and more angled, than the usual floor pedals.

I think I have my keyboard and seat positions currently very similar to normal piano heights

Should setup my stand and seat different to fix this problem?
Are organ manuals (and seats) higher than piano manuals?

[image]

Comment: Does your knee hit the stand when you put your foot on the sustain pedal?

Comment: No. I added the expression pedal later, had no problems before and did not change anything so far.

Comment: Your knee should be nowhere near hitting the stand for this kind of keyboard stand. Sounds like you're sitting way too high.

Answer (score 3):

I use exactly the same stand - very good! But it's on its lowest height, so maybe 3 or 4" lower than yours. I have no problem with a damper pedal and expression pedal, in fact, I mounted those two along with a volume pedal, on a piece of ply, making it easier to set up and break down. And, they don't wander around. My k'bd is 3-4" high, so I can't really see what the problem is, except your seat is too high, or your foot to knee measurement is quite long.

My damper is on the right, central is the expression, and left is the volume (swell) pedal. It all works well, for me, but if not for you, the stand needs changing for maybe a 'Z' stand, giving more room underneath. When I use more than one k'bd, the higher ones are more tilted than yours appears to be, as well.

Comment: It seems like you're recommending either a higher stand or a lower seat, correct?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - can't see another alternative, short of a different stand.

Comment: Agreed. Just wasn't sure that was your point. I'm terrible at reading between the lines, though.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - they're quite simple: let's face it, in treble clef, they're FACE..!